# Can I use a function to combine information from 2 different worksheets? More than VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 different worksheets in Excel, and I am trying to combine certain information from them into another worksheet. Here is an example:

Worksheet 1:

```
Item    Quantity   Cost    Expiration
cookies        1   $1.00       7/1/18
```

Worksheet 2:

```
Item    Quantity   Cost    Expiration
cookies        3   $1.00       9/1/18
```

I would like to find a function or formula so that worksheet 3 could combine information from the other 2 worksheets. It would have the quantities added together, and the earliest expiration date.

So I would like worksheet 3 to look like this:

```
Item    Quantity   Cost    Expiration
cookies        4   $1.00       7/1/18
```

Comment: OK, this looks like `VLOOKUP`, `IF`, and simple addition.  What part are you having trouble with?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Question1, how can I know I need to returen Cost value as $1.00? Question 2, if this is the whole tables in Workbook without other rows? If this is the result you need, for Quantity you can use this formula: =SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B) for Expiration you can use this formula: =MIN(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet2!D:D)

Comment: google `3d SUMIFS Excel`

Comment: @Lee those formulas worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Suppose the cookies on worksheet 1 cost $0.75 and the cookies on worksheet 2 cost $1.00.  How would they be combined?  What's the rule for combining the differing expiration dates?  Lee's comment may have given you what you need, but the question is extremely ambiguous, with endless ways to interpret the requirements.  That's not useful for either answerers or other readers.

Answer (score 0):

For Quantity you can use this formula： `=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:B)`

For Expiration you can use this formula: `=MIN(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet2!D:D)`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Write **Cookies** in Cell A2 of Sheet3.

In Cell B2 of Sheet3 write this formula:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP($A$2, Sheet1!$A$2:$D$2, 2, FALSE))+SUM(VLOOKUP($A$2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$2, 2, FALSE))
```

In Cell C2 of Sheet3 write this one:

```
=MIN(VLOOKUP($A$2, Sheet1!$A$2:$D$2,3, FALSE))*MIN(VLOOKUP($A$2, Sheet2!$A$2:$D$2, 3, FALSE))
```

**Note:**, if "Cost Column" have has values other that 1, then in Cell C2 of Sheet3 write this Array Formula:

```
{=MIN(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2=A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$2))}
```

In Cell D2 of Sheet3 write this Array Formula:

```
{=MIN(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2=A2,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$2,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$2))}
```

**N.B.** Finish Array Formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.